# Bind a WPF data grid to multiple data sources

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have created a data grid in WPF and have 2 lists. I want to bind one column to one list and rest of the columns to another list.
Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I suggest you mark at least the Robert Fraser and Ben Collier answers.  Both gave good solutions to your questions that, if they didn't completely get you where you needed to be, at least put you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I am new to stack overflow and did not realize the importance of it. I have marked response by Robert as it really helped me. Most of the other reponses are my own.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, You cant. The datagrid is an ItemsControl which has one ItemsSource property.

What i would do is build a view model which is a composite object that contains one of each of the items (from the two lists). then you could bind to a collection of these.

```
public class CompositeItem{
   public Object ItemFromListOne { get; set; }
   public Object ItemFromListTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Aran, Thanks for your response. I am doing it the way you suggested. I have merged my sources into a single list and made merged list as data source of the datagrid.